# WPF ListBox loading items on demand and case if there is not enough items in the list

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm trying to implement the logic to load items in a ListBox on demand. Whenever user scrolls with a scrollbar or a mousewheel it will check if there is more data and load it. The only problem I have is when there is not enough items to fill the ListBox so ScrollBar is not visible and as a result neither MouseWheel Event nor `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffsetProperty ValueChanged` event handler is called.

```
  static void AssignCommand(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FrameworkElement element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
            element.Loaded -= AssignCommand;

            ScrollViewer scrollViewer = GetDescendantByType<ScrollViewer>(element);
            if (scrollViewer == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("ScrollViewer not found.");
            }

            element.MouseWheel += delegate
            {
                // listbox not called
            };

            scrollViewer.MouseWheel += delegate
            {
                // scrollviewer not called
                var visibility = scrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
                if (visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    //try to fetch data
                }
            };

            var dpd = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ScrollViewer.VerticalOffsetProperty, typeof(ScrollViewer));
            dpd.AddValueChanged(scrollViewer, delegate
            {
                bool atBottom = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset
                                    >= scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;

                if (atBottom)
                {
                    var atEnd = GetAtEndCommand(element);
                    atEnd?.Execute(null);
                }
            });
        }
```

I'm surprised that ListBox.MouseWheel event is not called even though it's not handled by underlying ScrollViewer. I want to take advantage of `ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility` and if it's not visible then it should try to fetch data whenever user scrolls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is `PreviewMouseWheel`

```
 scrollViewer.PreviewMouseWheel += delegate
            {
                var visibility = scrollViewer.ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility;
                if (visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
                {
                    //try to fetch data
                }
            };
```